Decide algorithmically whether a black box geometric transformation is homeomorphic
Suppose a black-box function $F: \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m'\times n'}$ that performs some kind of geometric transformation of a raster image.
What it means to be a geometric transformation of a raster image: there's a fixed secondary mapping $g: (i, j) \leftrightarrow (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$ that goes between coordinates of an image matrix and a square tiling of a region of the Euclidean plane.  This mapping is the same for both input and output, and defined by a single parameter, the resolution $r$: $x_1(i) = ri$, $x_2(i) = r(i+1)$, etc.  (Note: I cannot vary the resolution.  It is baked into the black box.)  The input matrix is mapped onto the plane using this secondary mapping.  $F$ performs its geometric transformation on the plane.  Assume without loss of generality that the result is still planar (we can always compose the real $F$ with an optical projection back onto a plane).  Then it draws a grid with resolution $r$ (but potentially a different size than the input tiling) over the image of the transformed input, picks a value for each cell of that grid based on some sort of average of all the points in the cell, and that's the matrix you get as output.
Yes, there are a lot of handwaves in there.  This is the game on offer.
I am looking for an algorithm which can decide (probabilistically) whether the transformation performed by $F$ is homeomorphic.  An algorithm that decides whether $F$ is diffeomorphic may also do the job, I think none of the concrete examples of $F$ I care about are going to be homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.
A more image-processing way to put it is that I want to know whether $F$ preserves adjacency of pixels.
Is there a standard algorithm for this job, or one that can easily be adapted to it?
$F$ does not necessarily have any stronger property than homeomorphism (e.g. it might not be projective, conformal, or equiareal) and it may map some input pixel coordinates to infinity (e.g. $x' = \log x$ is a legitimate thing for $F$ to do).  $F$ is supposed to be invertible, but an implementation of $F^{-1}$ might not be available, and the algorithm I'm looking for must, if given a black box that is not actually invertible (or not actually continuous), correctly declare it to be non-homeomorphic.
The actual raster images I care about are grayscale with 1-bit transparency (mathematically speaking, each cell of the image matrix is either a real number in $[0,1]$ or a special "not part of image" marker).

How do you define adjacency of pixels? What is a pixel in your setting - a rectangle? Can $F$ then produce non-rectangular pixels? How can I tell whether a point belongs to a pixel after the trabsformation? Do you have access to $F^{-1}$?

@lightxbulb You put a matrix into $F$ and you get a matrix back out. That's what "transformation of a raster image" means. If that doesn't nail down what I mean by "pixel" and "adjacency" enough then please clarify what information is missing. In the case of immediate interest to me $F^{-1}$ is available, but not necessarily in general; if this is only possible when $F^{-1}$ is available that's an interesting thing to know.

You mentioned that $F$ is a geometric transformations of an image, so I expected to have $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and you somehow take your array of numbers an construct a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(ih_x, jh_y) = a_{ij}$, and some interpolation happens inbetween. If you define $F$ to act only on the values, i.e. $F:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, then I do not understand in what sense this is deemed a geometric transformation. If you want $F$ to be a homemorphism, then $F^{-1}$ must not only exist but both $F$ and $F^{-1}$ must be continuous.

A raster image matrix does not in itself provide a definition of adjacency.  There are adjacency matrices defined for directed or undirected graphs, but your post does not seem concerned with graph theory.  Please clarify what things are adjacent

@lightxbulb I guess this is only obvious if you've just been up to your eyeballs in image processing code the way I have.  Yes, I really am talking about a black box $F:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m'\times n'}$.  I have attempted to edit the question and clarify what I want.  I know that $F^{-1}$ must exist and both $F$ and $F^{-1}$ must be continuous for $F$ to be a homeomorphism; however, I need an algorithm that can detect when $F$ is not continuous or not invertible and will correctly label such functions as non-homeomorphic.

@hardmath Each cell of a raster image matrix is adjacent to the eight cells that can be reached from it in a single chess king's move. (Is this not implicit in the term "raster image matrix"?)

@zwol Both hardmath and I are confused because what you have described is adjacency in the graph sense, while simulatneously you are talking about a geometric transformation. After your edits, my guess is that you call geometric transformation and $F$ the whole process of: starting with  your raster image matrix, interpolating its values on a grid in $\mathbb{R}^2$, applying what mathematicians would call a geometric transformation, and then resampling. If this is so, then $F$ really isn't a geometric transformation but the composition I described above.

Assuming you are given some array of numbers $A\in\mathbb{R}^{W\times H}$, in order to talk about a geometric transformation of an image, we need to construct a function, e.g. $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, representing the image. We can require that it interpolates the data at the grid points: $g(i h_x, jh_y) = A_{ij}$ for $0\leq i\leq W-1$ and $0\leq j\leq H-1$, typically one requires that for points inbetween the values are interpolated somehow (for example nearest neighbour, bilinear, or bicubic interpolation). In any case, if we apply the transformation $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ to our image $g$, then the transformed image is $u(x,y) = g(F^{-1}(x,y))$.
Whether $F$ is homeomorphic isn't really related to $g$ in any way, you just need that it is bijective (which implies that $F^{-1}$ exists) and that $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are continuous. The intuitive idea of continuity is that if you make two points $p,q\in\mathbb{R}^2$ close enough, then $F(p), F(q)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ can also be made arbitrarily close. That is, $F$ is continuous at $p$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta(\epsilon, p)>0$ such that for any $q$ satisfying $\|p-q\|_2<\delta$ we have $\|F(p)-F(q)\|<\epsilon$.
A naive idea for testing continuity would be to take points and make them closer, and as those get closer we should expect that their transformed versions also get closer (i.e. $\|F(p)-F(q)\|_2$ should go to zero in the limit). This is complicated by the fact that this should hold along any direction and at any point. Moreover you would need to check this for both $F$ and $F^{-1}$. And on top of that there is the fact that floating point numbers are not perfect.
Note: I believe this is an XY problem based on the fact that you did not know what a geometric transformation and a homeomorphism are. I would suggest that you add details on the actual setting your are dealing with along with what you are actually trying to achieve, even if an informal description of this.

Please advise whether my edits to the question resolve the things you were unclear on.  Perhaps the key issue is that I do not have the ability to feed $F$ pairs of arbitrarily positioned points.

@zwol I still do not understand how $F$ is a geometric transformation. What is the $m\times n$? The resolution of your image? Why is $m'\times n'$ of different size? Are you actually including the interpolation, geometric transformation, and a subsequent resampling, in $F$?

@zwol:  Perhaps you should explain what ability you do have to "feed $F$" points.  Typically when a function is described algorithmically as "a black box", it means precisely that you have the ability to give $F$ inputs and observe the outputs.  There is a basic result as to a homeomorphism known as invariance of domain.  To wit: if $mn \neq m' n'$, no homeomorphism is possible.
